# Form Validation with Semantic-UI-React

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using the official [Semantic UI React](http://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction) components to create a web application. I have a form on my sign up page, which contains an email field, a password field, and a confirm password field.

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, Form, Message} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import {signUp} from '../../actions/auth';

class SignUp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleSubmit(e, {formData}) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //
        // Potentially need to manually validate fields here?
        //

        // Send a POST request to the server with the formData
        this.props.dispatch(signUp(formData)).then(({isAuthenticated}) => {
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                // Redirect to the home page if the user is authenticated
                this.props.router.push('/');
            }
        }
    }
    render() {
        const {err} = this.props;

        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} error={Boolean(err)}>
                <Form.Input label="Email" name="email" type="text"/>
                <Form.Input label="Password" name="password" type="password"/>
                <Form.Input label="Confirm Password" name="confirmPassword" type="password"/>

                {err &&
                    <Message header="Error" content={err.message} error/>
                }

                <Button size="huge" type="submit" primary>Sign Up</Button>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, I am used to the regular Semantic UI library, which has a [Form Validation addon](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html). Usually, I would define the rules like so in a separate JavaScript file

```
$('.ui.form').form({
    fields: {
        email: {
            identifier: 'email',
            rules: [{
                type: 'empty',
                prompt: 'Please enter your email address'
            }, {
                type: 'regExp',
                value: "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?",
                prompt: 'Please enter a valid email address'
            }]
        },
        password: {
            identifier: 'password',
            rules: [{
                type: 'empty',
                prompt: 'Please enter your password'
            }, {
                type: 'minLength[8]',
                prompt: 'Your password must be at least {ruleValue} characters'
            }]
        },
        confirmPassword: {
            identifier: 'confirmPassword',
            rules: [{
                type: 'match[password]',
                prompt: 'The password you provided does not match'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a similar method using the Semantic UI React components for validating the form? I've searched through the documentation without any success, and there doesn't seem to be examples of validation using this Semantic UI React library.

Do I instead need to validate each field by hand in the `handleSubmit` function? What is the best way to fix this problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Through the course of learning React I stumbled upon forms, which I felt react might be having as part of its core features. But unfortunately it doesn't. It has become a reason for me not to like react much compared to Angular.

Comment: @PankajPrakash, this question is a few years old, and there are many great options available for form validation now. I'm now using `formik` and `yup`, which does a great job of validating forms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We even have a better option, though not provided by semantic-ui-react -> [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/) + [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup)
Formik: helps in managing form state
Yup: helps in the validation of that state

I have the below component which is basically an edit form created using semantic-ui-react.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Form, Modal, Message, Divider } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";


class EditAboutGrid extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      userBasic,
      editBasicModal,
      closeModal
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          firstName: userBasic.firstName,
          lastName: userBasic.lastName,
          bio: userBasic.bio,
        }}
        validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
          firstName: yup
            .string()
            .required("Name cannot be empty"),
          lastName: yup
            .string()
            .required("Name cannot be empty"),
          bio: yup
            .string()
            .max(1000, "Maximum characters exceed 1000")
            .nullable()
        })}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          //do your stuff here like api calls
        }}
        render={({
          values,
          errors,
          handleChange,
          handleSubmit,
          isSubmitting,
          dirty,
          setFieldValue
        }) => (
          <Modal open={editBasicModal} size="small">
            <Modal.Header>Your basic details</Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Content scrolling>
              {errors.firstName && <Message error content={errors.firstName} />}
              {errors.lastName && <Message error content={errors.lastName} />}
              {errors.bio && <Message error content={errors.bio} />}

              <Form loading={isSubmitting}>
                <Form.Group inline widths="equal">
                  <Form.Input
                    required
                    label="First Name"
                    fluid
                    type="text"
                    name="firstName"
                    value={values.firstName}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    error={errors.firstName !== undefined}
                  />
                  <Form.Input
                    required
                    label="Last Name"
                    fluid
                    type="text"
                    name="lastName"
                    value={values.lastName}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    error={errors.lastName !== undefined}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.TextArea
                  label="Bio"
                  type="text"
                  name="bio"
                  value={values.bio}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  rows={3}
                  error={errors.bio !== undefined}
                />
              </Form>
            </Modal.Content>
            <Modal.Actions open={true}>
              <Button
                onClick={() => (dirty ? closeModal(true) : closeModal(false))}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
              <Button
                primary
                type="submit"
                onClick={handleSubmit}
                loading={isSubmitting}
                disabled={isSubmitting || !isEmpty(errors) || !dirty}>
                Update
              </Button>
            </Modal.Actions>
          </Modal>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And this form is called using:

```
  <EditAboutGrid
    editBasicModal={this.state.editBasicModal}
    userBasic={this.state.user.basic}
    closeModal={this.closeModal}
  />
```

`initialValues` is the place where the things start. Here you pass on the initial/default values to the inputs of your form. `values`(in form) will pick data value from this default.

`validationSchema` is the place where all validation happens using `yup`

`onSubmit` would be called on the form submission.

Handling form using Formik + yup is very easy. I am loving it.

Comment: Just a note for people using this code.

You will require a `isEmpty()` function as follows:

```
function isEmpty(arg){
  return (
    arg == null || // Check for null or undefined
    arg.length === 0 || // Check for empty String (Bonus check for empty Array)
    (typeof arg === 'object' && Object.keys(arg).length === 0) // Check for empty Object or Array
  );
}
```

The Formik `render()` function has been deprecated as of the most recent version at 2020-12-30.

Comment: Or you can import it from `lodash`

Answer (score 9):

For the most part, you have to validate forms by hand. However, RSUI includes a couple of tools to make things a bit easier, in particular the error prop on `<Form>` and `<Form.Input>`

Here's an example of a form I put together recently. It could use a bit of refactoring, but it basically works by tying each input to state with an `onChange()` function, and passing a callback to the submit function which controls the visibility of the loading screen and the "Success. Thank you for submitting" portion of the form.

```
export default class MeetingFormModal extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      location: '',
      firstNameError: false,
      lastNameError: false,
      emailError: false,
      locationError: false,
      formError: false,
      errorMessage: 'Please complete all required fields.',
      complete: false,
      modalOpen: false
    }

    this.submitMeetingForm = this.submitMeetingForm.bind(this);
    this.successCallback = this.successCallback.bind(this);
  }


  successCallback() {
    this.setState({
      complete: true
    })
    setTimeout( () => {this.setState({modalOpen: false})}, 5000);
    this.props.hideLoading();
  }

  handleClose = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: false })
  handleOpen = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: true })

  submitMeetingForm() {

    let error = false;

    if (this.state.studentFirstName === '') {
      this.setState({firstNameError: true})
      error = true
    } else {
      this.setState({firstNameError: false})
      error = false
    }
    if (this.state.studentLastName === '') {
      this.setState({lastNameError: true})
      error = true
    } else {
      this.setState({lastNameError: false})
      error = false
    }
    if (this.state.email === '') {
      this.setState({emailError: true})
      error = true
    } else {
      this.setState({emailError: false})
      error = false
    }
    if (this.state.location === '') {
      this.setState({locationError: true})
      error = true
    } else {
      this.setState({locationError: false})
      error = false
    }

    if (error) {
      this.setState({formError: true})
      return
    } else {
      this.setState({formError: false})
    }


    let meeting = {
      first_name: this.state.firstName,
      last_name: this.state.lastName,
      email: this.state.email,
      location: this.state.location,

    this.props.createMeeting(meeting, this.successCallback)
    this.props.showLoading();
  }

  capitalize(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Modal
        trigger={<Button onClick={this.handleOpen} basic color='blue'>Schedule Now</Button>}
        open={this.state.modalOpen}
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        closeIcon={true}
      >
        <Modal.Header>Schedule Your Interview</Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Content>
          {!this.state.complete ?
          <Modal.Description>
            <Form error={this.state.formError}>
              <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                <Form.Field>
                  <Form.Input required={true} onChange={(e) => this.setState({firstName: e.target.value})} label='First Name' placeholder="First Name..." error={this.state.firstNameError}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                  <Form.Input required={true} onChange={(e) => this.setState({lastName: e.target.value})} label='Last Name' placeholder="Last Name..." error={this.state.lastNameError}/>
                </Form.Field>
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Field >
                <Form.Input required={true} onChange={(e) => this.setState({email: e.target.value})} label='Email' placeholder="Email..." error={this.state.emailError}/>
              </Form.Field>
              <Form.Field>
                <Form.Input required={true} onChange={(e) => this.setState({location: e.target.value})} label='Location' placeholder='City, State/Province, Country...' error={this.state.locationError}/>
              </Form.Field>
            </Form>
          </Modal.Description>
          : 
            <div className='modal-complete'>
              <Image src='/images/check.png' />
              <p>Thanks for scheduling a meeting, {this.capitalize(this.state.name)}. We've received your information and we'll be in touch shortly.</p>
            </div>
          }
        </Modal.Content>
        {!this.state.complete ?
        <Modal.Actions>
          <Button color='red' onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
          <Button positive icon='checkmark' labelPosition='right' content="Submit" onClick={this.submitMeetingForm} />
        </Modal.Actions>
        : null }
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `let meeting = { ...` is not closed

Comment: Now It seems that I can avoid Formik or Redux-forms to manage any form "ephimeral" state. Nice sample, thanks @jmknoll

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is several years old, but this was something I struggled with doing while using the (relatively) newer React functional components and Hooks API. In my case, I just wanted to validate that the user input was a valid email address. I ended up getting the behavior I was looking for with the code below.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import EmailValidator from 'email-validator';


function MyFormComponentExample() {
    const [emailInput, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [validEmail, validateEmail] = useState(true);

    return (
    <Form>
        <Form.Input
            icon='envelope'
            iconPosition='left'
            label='Email'
            placeholder='Email Address'
            required
            value={emailInput}
            onChange={e => {
                setEmail(e.target.value);                               
                validateEmail(EmailValidator.validate(e.target.value));
            }}
            error={validEmail ? false : {
                content: 'Please enter a valid email address.',
                pointing: 'below'
            }}
        />
    </Form>
    );
}

export default MyFormComponentExample;
```

Once I figured it out, I thought this structure was simple enough, but if anyone has feedback about a better pattern or approach to perform this I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

> Do I instead need to validate each field by hand in the handleSubmit
>   function?

Sad, but true. SUIR [doesn't have](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/407) form validation at now. However, you can use HOC to work with forms like [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin for validation.
Plugin name : [formsy-semantic-ui-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formsy-semantic-ui-react)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. But it's unfortunate that `semantic-ui-react` does not have this capability when `semantic-ui` does. `formsy-semantic-ui-react` is a third party package, so I'm concerned that it will not get the same amount of support that an official package would get

Answer (score 0):

The code below essentially sets state to each components name and associated value.  (I.E, state might look like {marketSide:buy, price:50, quantity:9} I also stuff the forms error info into state as well, taking advantage of yup's default behavior to not validate fields that are not mentioned by the validation schema.

Important points:

1) The call to schema.validate(someObjectToValidate, yupProperties), (where someObjectToValidate is just this.state), should pass in {abortEarly:false} as the properties object, to override yups default behavior to stop validation once a single error has been encountered, as our form's message component displays all errors to the user.

2)If yup validation fails, yup throws an exception, so we catch the exception and pick off the error info we are interested in, and update our state with this error.

3)We must use the 'callback form' of this.setState(...), since setState is asynchronous, so that validation of the state object only happens after state has been updated.

4)if yup validation succeeds, we clear our errors and errorPath arrays.

5)This is a quick solution, I am checking the errorPaths array several times on each render. It would be better to store the errorPath and error info on in a json object keyed by the component's name, instead of in two arrays, to improve the current solution's (2 arrays * N fields * N potential errors = O(2n^2) performance.

6)Disregard the long style '`<Form.Field control={Radio}>`' notation, you could use the shorter `<Input>, <Button>, <Radio>,` etc style. This syntax has nothing to do with the validation. Also ignore the divs.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Checkbox, Form, Input, Radio, Select, Message,  Label } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import * as yup from 'yup';


const options = [
  { text: 'buy', value: 'buy' },
  { text: 'sell', value: 'sell' },
]

class OrderEntryV3 extends Component {
  state = {
      errorPaths:[],
      errors:[]
  }

  constructor(props){
      super(props);
  }


  schema = yup.object().shape({
    quantity: yup.number().required().positive().integer(),
    price:  yup.number().required().positive(),
    marketSide: yup.string().required(),
    orderType : yup.string().required()
  });



  handleChange = (e, component) => {
      this.setState({[component.name]:component.value}, ()=>this.schema.validate(this.state, {abortEarly:false})
         .then(valid=>this.setState({errorPaths:[], errors:[]})) //called if the entire form is valid
         .catch(err=>this.setState({errors:err.errors, errorPaths: err.inner.map(i=>i.path) }))) //called if any field is invalid
    };


  render() {

    return (
<div id="oeform-content">
    <div id="oeform-left">
      <Form>
          <Form.Field  error={this.state.errorPaths.includes('marketSide')} name="marketSide" control={Select} label='Market side' options={options} placeholder='market side' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <Form.Field  error={this.state.errorPaths.includes('quantity')} type='number' name="quantity" control={Input} label='Quantity' placeholder='quantity' onChange={this.handleChange}/>

          <Form.Group>
              <label><b>Order type</b></label>  
        <Form.Field error={this.state.errorPaths.includes('orderType')} >
          <Radio
            label='market'
            name='orderType'
            value='market'
            checked={this.state.orderType === 'market'}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field error={this.state.errorPaths.includes('orderType')}>
          <Radio
            label='limit'
            name='orderType'
            value='limit'
            checked={this.state.orderType === 'limit'}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </Form.Field>
    </Form.Group>
        <Form.Field error={this.state.errorPaths.includes('price')} name='price' control={Input} type='number' label='Price' placeholder='price' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <Form.Field control={Button} disabled={!!this.state.errors.length}>Submit</Form.Field>
        <Message visible={!!this.state.errors.length} warning
        header='Please correct the following issues: '
        list={this.state.errors}/>
      </Form>
    </div>
    <div id="oeform-right">
        <p>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</p>
    </div>
</div>
    )
  }
}

export default OrderEntryV3
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is rather couple of years old and is not a complete solution for the question asked but anyone looking today might find this useful as I was looking for the same and ran into this thread.  Though semantic-ui-react does not have a form validation that I can find, but it has a nice way to show form validation errors. You still have to do the validation on your own.  Refer to [semantic-ui-react forms documentation page](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/) for an example of how it shows validation errors.  It also has a feature to show success message.  I have created an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-0qn4q) of how you can control the error message based on the state.  In this example, you can use the "Show Gender Error" checkbox to toggle the error message on the Gender input.

Comment: Where does Semantic UI React forms documentation say anything about validation?

Answer (score -1):

For validate form in semantic-ui you can simply achieve without any plugin

```
<Form.Field
      id='form-input-control-project-name'
      control={Input}
      label='Project Name'
      placeholder='Project name'
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      error={this.state.projectName}
    />
```

*this.state.projectName* **In This variable you have to store false/error message**

If *the value is false* not display error **otherwise display error**

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Formik](https://formik.org) to do validation.

And I have created a library to bind Formik and Semantic UI React.

https://github.com/JT501/formik-semantic-ui-react

A quick example:
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/login-form-ftqwx?file=/src/LoginForm.tsx)