# semantic-ui-react form validation with Yup

Tags: semantic-ui-react, formik, yup

I read this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724225/form-validation-with-semantic-ui-react) but that doesn't really answer the question. I am using formik and semantic-ui-react.
Is is possible to use Yup with semantic-ui-react?
If yes could someone provide an example?

Answer (score 6):

yes it is possible , Here is one way to do it. paste this code in codesandbox.io and install the dependencies like formik yup and semantic-ui-react

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { Button, Checkbox, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstname: "",
        lastname: ""
      }}
      onSubmit={values => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values));
      }}
      validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
        firstname: yup.string().required("This field is required"),
        lastname: yup.string().required()
      })}
      render={({
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        handleSubmit
      }) => {
        return (
          <Form>
            <Form.Field>
              <label>First Name</label>
              <input
                placeholder="First Name"
                name="firstname"
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
              />
            </Form.Field>
            {touched.firstname && errors.firstname && (
              <div> {errors.firstname}</div>
            )}
            <Form.Field>
              <label>Last Name</label>
              <input
                placeholder="Last Name"
                name="lastname"
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
              />
            </Form.Field>
            {touched.lastname && errors.lastname && (
              <div> {errors.lastname}</div>
            )}
            <Form.Field>
              <Checkbox label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions" />
            </Form.Field>
            <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    />
  </>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: `TypeError: _this.props.onSubmit is not a function` error on submit.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include onSubmit attribute in <Formik> @TheCoder

Comment: @RahilAhmad is there any way i can send a parameter to handlesubmit that i can later on recieve in onsubmit?

Comment: @RishiSahu you can make that part of initial state, that way you can update that from helpers and receive it in on submit internally or you can manually call the handleSumbit with values with any thing else you want to pass to ti

Comment: @RahilAhmad I did try to pass the params to handleSubmit but I don't receive those params in onSubmit function.