# How to show warning message only for Form.Dropdown in Semantic-UI React?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I can't find this functional in official documentation.
Only what I can find is warning for entire form, like

```
<Form warning>
...
<Form.Group widths="equal">
    ...
<Form.Dropdown
    ...
/>
<Message
    warning
    header="Could you check something!"
    list={[
        "That e-mail has been subscribed, but you have not yet clicked the verification link in your e-mail."
    ]}
/>
```

But I need message only for Form.Dropdown.

I use

```
<Form.Group widths="equal">
```

to position multiple items on the same line, and if I write code like I show above in result I get Message which will be shown in line after Dropdown.

Me need Message element which will be shown below Dropdown.

Comment: Check this - https://medium.com/@krandles/validating-forms-in-semantic-ui-react-a057957f1dd6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form Validation with Semantic-UI-React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724225/form-validation-with-semantic-ui-react)

Comment: unfortunately this is not what I need

Answer (score 0):

I found answer.

```
<div className="field">
    <Form.Dropdown
        ...
    />
    <Message
        warning
        visible
        header="Could you check something!"
        list={[
        "That e-mail has been subscribed, but you have not yet clicked the verification link in your e-mail."
        ]}
    />
</div>
```

Use

```
<div className="field">...</div>
```

as wrapper.